Register GKE cluster to external ArgoCD
Is it possible to register a GKE cluster to an ArgoCD instance running on another cluster created on bare-metal and orchestrated by rancher?
I found this guide but it seems that it only works between clusters on GKE while on the side of ArgoCD docs i didn't find anything relevant
